# My Nexus 4 won't upgrade - I keep getting an error

Tags: updates, nexus-4, system-error

I have an unrooted Nexus 4 and running Android 5.0. When the 5.0.1 OTA update came out I could download it and start installing it and then get screen that said error with the android robot on it's back but with no helpful information. I just tried again with 5.1 and I got the same problem. I factory reset my phone and it still doesn't work!

Please can someone advise on what to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @bmdixon I haven't rooted my phone so I don't know how that could have happened. Is there another way? I am a bit of a noob when it comes to this. Last time I tried to flash my phone it didn't work...

Comment: What does the error say? It will usually (always?) show something else other than just 'error'. Knowing why it is failing might give a clue as to how to fix it.

Comment: I'll get back to you in a few minutes, once it has finished downloading and installing. Is there something I have to press to get a more detailed error message. You are correct that one would expect something more useful than just "error"...

Comment: @bmdixon I just tried again and it only says "Error!" underneath a picture of the robot on it's back.  It will stay on this screen until I press the volume down and power keys simultaneously...

Comment: I'm not sure then, without knowing _why_ it errors I'm not sure what else to suggest, apart from flashing a factory image which (if you haven't already unlocked the bootloader) would mean wiping all your data from the phone.

Comment: @David Did you happen to try clearing your cache partition? Instructions found on this page- http://www.gottabemobile.com/2014/12/15/nexus-android-5-0-1-problems-fixes/

Comment: Yes I tried that but it didn't help. I just learned how to root it and flash the update from there and now everything is fine. The sideloading method didn't seem to work and since I had already factory reset my phone I thought I may as well root it...